# Overriding js file for FilteredSelectMultiple widget

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am sorry if this a basic question, but I am new to django and could not find any new info about it.

I have implemented `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget to my user form. Now I would like to make some minor changes to widget itself (make translations, edit tooltips etc.). To do so, I copied and edited original `js` file. Now I would like to override original file with edited one.

For this file I created `js` directory in static. But then I am trying to add it in my `Media` class loaded widget remains unchanged.

How should I do it correctly?

My code in `forms.py`

```
class DrgSkaiciuokle(forms.Form):
    bazine_kaina = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, required=True,
                                      label="Bazinė kaina",
                                      initial= BazineKaina.objects.get(),

    def clean_bazine_kaina(self):
        bazine_kaina = self.cleaned_data['bazine_kaina']
        return bazine_kaina

    drg_pasirinkimas = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=DRGkodas.objects.all(),
                                                      label="Pasirinkite atvejį sudarančius DRG",
                                                      widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("DRG kodai", is_stacked=False),
                                                      required=True)


    class Media:

        css = {
           'all': ('/static/css/widgets.css',),
         }

        js = (
            '/static/js/SelectFilter2.js',
            )


    def clean_drg_pasirinkimas(self):
        drg_pasirinkimas = self.cleaned_data['drg_pasirinkimas']
        return drg_pasirinkimas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some midnight thinking and more digging I find out a solution myself.

Turns out I needed to define all used `js` files in `Media` class.

My amended code:

```
class DrgSkaiciuokle(forms.Form):
    bazine_kaina = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, required=True,
                                      label="Bazinė kaina",
                                      initial= BazineKaina.objects.get(),

    def clean_bazine_kaina(self):
        bazine_kaina = self.cleaned_data['bazine_kaina']
        return bazine_kaina

    drg_pasirinkimas = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=DRGkodas.objects.all(),
                                                      label="Pasirinkite atvejį sudarančius DRG",
                                                      widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("DRG kodai", is_stacked=False),
                                                      required=True)


    class Media:

        css = {
           'all': ('/static/css/widgets.css',),
         }

        js = (
            #copy required files to directory of your choice
            '/static/js/core.js',
            '/static/js/jquery.init.js',
            '/static/js/jquery.js',
            '/static/js/SelectBox.js',
            '/static/js/SelectFilter2.js',
            )


    def clean_drg_pasirinkimas(self):
        drg_pasirinkimas = self.cleaned_data['drg_pasirinkimas']
        return drg_pasirinkimas
```

EDIT: Also important thing! If you are trying to develop site using Chrome after changing js files do hard Chrome reset using `ctl-shift-r` combo, because Chrome tend to keep old files until you completely close it. So after modifying js code and refreshing site it will show old code! This knowledge would have saved me few days of digging and pulling my hair...